# Scenekit repeat texture added through SCNShadable

Tags: scenekit

I've added a `uniform sampler2D uMySampler;` through SCNShadable. I believe i'm not seeing the texture because it's not set to be repeat wrapping.

The sample code that i've found does it this way programatically:

```
myMat?.diffuse.wrapS = SCNWrapMode.repeat
myMat?.diffuse.wrapT = SCNWrapMode.repeat
```

But how do i set the wrapS on `uMySampler`?

As a fallback i think i could get away by doing `fract(myTexCoord)` but that might mess up mipmapping?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let myTexture = SCNMaterialProperty( contents: UIImage(named: "art.scnassets/myTexture.png") );
myTexture.wrapS = SCNWrapMode.repeat
```

This is the trick, not sure if i find this very intuitive.